# What do the player trait acronyms mean in NFL Pro 2012?

Tags: nfl-pro-2012

I'd like to figure out what the player trait acronyms mean in NFL Pro 2012 for the iPad.

I believe that this is a Madden game.

Here are the traits for the wide receiver: CTH CAR AWR SPD ACC AGI

I think that SPD means "speed" and ACC means "acceleration" but I have no idea what the other ones mean.

Here are the traits for the safety: TAK MCV ZCV SPD ACC AGI

I would love to find documentation which lists out the acronyms and explains what each one does.  Even better would be a short strategy guide that explains what I should spend my player points on (e.g., given the choice between spending five points on my safety's TAK or SPD, which should I choose?).

Comment: Taking a wild guess: CTH = Catch, CAR = Carry, AGI = Agility.  For the safety: TAK = Tackle, MCV = Man Coverage, ZCV = Zone Coverage.  I'm not sure what AWR could mean for the WR - Awareness??

Comment: @Jason, yeah, that should be right. These sound like the same traits in Madden proper.

Comment: Hmm ... actually, this isn't a Madden port, which is interesting because it does have an NFL license. Unfortunately, I had no success finding out anything about this game other than the extent to which microtransactions are involved. Hopefully someone else can find something to help you.

Answer (score 2):

For the Wide Receiver:

CTH = Catching
CAR = Carry
SPD = Speed
ACC = Acceleration
AGI = Agility

For the Safety:

TAK = Tackle
SPD = Speed
AWR = Awareness
MCV = Man Coverage
ZCV = Zone Coverage
AGI = Agility

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete list of all the player trait acronyms used by Madden:
[Definition of Attributes and Ratings in Madden Football](http://madden12.hubpages.com/hub/An-explanation-of-Attributes-and-Ratings-in-Madden-Football)

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.